# Display object attributes via a link_to from results of a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I seem to be getting a little muddled here, so clarification more than anything needed here please.

I have a simple recipe app that enable users to upload recipes, and i have a section where all recipes with the category Dessert are listed

This class method (just a scope really) gives all recipes that have the category Dessert

```
def self.dessert_recipes
self.where(:category => "Desserts")

end
```

Within the controller I can then call this data to display in the view

```
@desserts = Recipe.dessert_recipes
```

And then in my view i can see the name of the recipe that has the category dessert

```
 <% @desserts.each do |r| %>
<p><%= link_to r.dish_name, recipe %></p>
  <p> <%= r.author %></p> # this doesnt exsist yet but it will
 <% end %>
```

What i want to do is click on the name of the recipe and it then take me to the show action for that particular recipe so that i can see the whole recipe from dish name to ingredients etc.

```
 <b><%= @recipe.dish_name %></b>
 <b><%= @recipe.catgegory %></b>
```

etc etc

The show action in the controller looks like this

```
 @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
```

Im guessing that i cant access the whole of the recipe as im trying to access it within a different instance class?  Some pointers on this would help so that i can get my head around what is happening

Comment: Most of this looks sound - I would expect it to be `link_to(r.dish_name, r)`, instead of what you have, but other than that I see nothing wrong with this. What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: getting undefined method recipe, where as i just want to get the id of the recipe to show all the attributes, thanks for the answer, will try later.. can i ask why just r ?

Comment: is it because I am passing r through my block?

Comment: Yeah, it's just `r` because that's what you're passing to the block - `r` is the Recipe object, `recipe` is undefined. That's also probably the cause of your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to MrTheWalrus for this answer

link_to(r.dish_name, r)